# Problem with writing full specialization for identifying void type

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, namespaces

I am trying to specialize is_void struct. Here is my code that I am trying to compile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct is_void
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_void<void>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", is_void<int>::value);
    printf("%d\n", is_void<void>::value);
}
```

But it fails with the compile error:

error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'is_void'
error: redefinition of 'is_void' as different kind of symbol

Right now I do not see any problems with this code. Appreciate any help.

Comment: cannot reproduce this:[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/0wjmJy), which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using cmake with clang on Mac OS and C++ 14.

Comment: What version of clang? Because I tried some and they worked as well, maybe its because of Mac

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `using namespace std;`

Comment: Yes, the problem was in using namespace std; but why is that?

Comment: Version of the clang is 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4).

Comment: Because there is [`std::is_void`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_void) which is defined differently.

Comment: Please avoid `using namespace std;`.  It is considered bad practice and will ruin your life (as shown in this example).  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the directive

```
using namespace std;
```

Otherwise there can be a conflict with the standard class `std::is_void` declared in the header `<type_traits>`.

The using directive in general is a source of problems with name resolutions.

Another approach is to use a qualified name as for example

```
::is_void<int>::value
```

But even a better approach is to place your declarations in a user namespace as for example

```
namespace usr
{
template<typename T>
struct is_void
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

namespace usr
{

template<typename T>
struct is_void
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

}

template<>
struct usr::is_void<void>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", usr::is_void<int>::value);
    printf("%d\n", usr::is_void<void>::value);
}
```

Also if you are using the C function `printf` then you should include header `<cstdio>`.

Comment: worth to mention [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)